# Getting the primary key of the row after inserting

Tags: android

I have a table called `foods` with primary key `food_id` which is `integer primary  key autoincrement. Now i know that`db.insert()`returns id (-1 if insertion failed) but the question is if this is the same id as`food_id`?? i want`food_id` after insertion because i am saving food item in a List as well at Application scope.

Comment: So you need to fetch that food_id value?

Comment: please have a look of my answer.

Comment: I like your answer +1. but i think you misunderstood me there. i want to know if the id returned by db.insert() is the same as my primary key of the table or not :-)

Comment: No, because it returned us the status of, is data inserted or not?

Comment: actually you can treat the returned value as food_id iff food_id is primary key autoincrement (1,1)

Comment: @KKD If there is a slight possibility of id conflict in this case? isn't it risky ?

Comment: @ShoebSiddique Yes bro you are right. it is not food_it.

Comment: there's no official documentation that says this, but I haven't seen a conflict in past two years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this-

```
        //local database variables
            private DataSourceUserRecords dataResource ; 
            private SQLiteDatabase _database = null;
            private Cursor _cursor = null;
            private MySqliteHelper DBHelper;
```

Add this code in onCreate or where you want to call.

```
    DBHelper = new MySqliteHelper(UploadImgService.this);
                _database = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                dataResource  = new DataSourceUserRecords(UploadImgService.this);
                dataResource.open();

              _cursor = _database.rawQuery("select * from "+MySqliteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

            _cursor.moveToFirst(); 

            while(_cursor.isAfterLast() == false){


                String _food_id =  _cursor.getInt(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.YOUR_COLUMN_ID));

                System.out.println("Food ID from db : " + _food_id );


                _cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            _cursor.close();
```